# making site id increment by 1

Tags: php, forms, auto-increment, increment

Hey guys im trying to make a quiz and currently I have ran into an issue, I have made it increment but not send the data, so I need to fix it but don't really know how to, I need the users to be able to select an option the data get sent to the next page but the page must also increase in increment.
this is what I have got

```
<form name="form2" method="post" >
<select name="answer">
<option value=$myrow['A']><?php echo $myrow['A']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['B']><?php echo $myrow['B']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['C']><?php echo $myrow['C']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['D']><?php echo $myrow['D']?></option>

 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" onclick = "window.location.href = 'testttts.php?id=<?php echo $count?>'"
```

any help would be great thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['i'])) {
    $i = $_POST['i'];
} else {
    $i = 0;
}

echo "increment: " . $i;
$i++;
?>

<form name="form2" method="post" >
<select name="answer">
<option value=$myrow['A']><?php echo $myrow['A']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['B']><?php echo $myrow['B']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['C']><?php echo $myrow['C']?></option>
<option value=$myrow['D']><?php echo $myrow['D']?></option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="i" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Continue" />
```

Comment: Kind of but I need the increment to happen in the address bar, so test.php?id=1, test.php?id=2, test.php?id=3 etc.

Comment: I fiddled around with it and got it to work, YOU ROCK! thank you very much!!